# ORA-04098:Trigger inválido y ha fallado en la revalidación

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

He creado un trigger que inserta datos en una tabla, antes de borrar un registro en otra tabla. El formato del trigger es el sgte:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TICKET_BK 
BEFORE DELETE ON BS_WEIGHTTICKET 
REFERENCING OLD AS VIEJO NEW AS NUEVO 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO BS_WEIGHTTICKET_BK (WEIGHTTICKET_KEY, MANDANT,   
     WEIGHTTICKET_NUMBER,   FIRMA,   INBOUND_OUTBOUND,   IS_BLANK,   
     LICENSE_PLATE,   LOCATION_CODE,   KUNDEN_KEY,   WEIGHT1,   WEIGHT2,   
     DIFF_WEIGHT,   DISCOUNT,   NET_WEIGHT,   IS_CLOSED,  IS_PRINTED,   
     ERSTELLT_AM,   ERSTELLT_VON,   DATUM_UPDATE,   USER_UPDATE,   
     CHECK_WEIGHT1,   CHECK_WEIGHT2,   CHECK_DIFF_WEIGHT,   DRIVER,   
     ENTRANCE_TIME,   EXIT_TIME,   COLLECTION_TYPE_CODE,   WORKFLOW_CODE,   
     CASH_NUMBER)  VALUES(  :NUEVO."WEIGHTTICKET_KEY",   :NUEVO."MANDANT",   
     :NUEVO."WEIGHTTICKET_NUMBER",   :NUEVO."FIRMA",   
     :NUEVO."INBOUND_OUTBOUND",   :NUEVO."IS_BLANK",   
     :NUEVO."LICENSE_PLATE",   :NUEVO."LOCATION_CODE",   
     :NUEVO."KUNDEN_KEY",   :NUEVO."WEIGHT1",   :NUEVO."WEIGHT2",   
     :NUEVO."DIFF_WEIGHT",   :NUEVO."DISCOUNT",   :NUEVO."NET_WEIGHT",   
     :NUEVO."IS_CLOSED",  :NUEVO."IS_PRINTED",   :NUEVO."ERSTELLT_AM",   
     :NUEVO."ERSTELLT_VON",   :NUEVO."DATUM_UPDATE",   :NUEVO."USER_UPDATE",   
     :NUEVO."CHECK_WEIGHT1",   :NUEVO."CHECK_WEIGHT2",   
     :NUEVO."CHECK_DIFF_WEIGHT",   :NUEVO."DRIVER",   
     :NUEVO."ENTRANCE_TIME",   :NUEVO."EXIT_TIME",   
     :NUEVO."COLLECTION_TYPE_CODE",   :NUEVO."WORKFLOW_CODE",   
     :NUEVO."CASH_NUMBER");
END;
```

Compila correctamente, ejecuto la sgte sentencia para ver si tiene errores, pero no los tiene:

```
select * from user_errors where name = 'TICKET_BK' and type = 'TRIGGER';
```

Ejecuto la sgte sentencia y me sale que es inválido, pero no me dice cuál es el error para solucionar:

```
select object_name from dba_objects where object_type = 'TRIGGER' and status = 'INVALID';
```

Alguien ya ha pasado por esto? Que solución le dieron? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si corres un `ALTER TRIGGER TICKET_BK compile ;`, qué sucede?

Comment: Me da la sgte salida: Trigger TICKET_BK altered. Pero luego lo ejecuto nuevamente y mismo error. Tambien probé con desactivar y reactivarlo, pero da el mismo error. `alter trigger TICKET_BK disable;` `alter trigger TICKET_BK enable;`

Comment: Lo extraño es que un trigger se invalida sólo cuando cambia algo en la estructura de los objetos que usa. De hecho, si intentas usar el trigger, oracle va a intentar recompilarlo y es ahí donde sale el error en el título. ¿Estás seguro que debes insertar :NUEVO y no :VIEJO? Estás borrando, así que no hay nada en NUEVO

Comment: Es así como dices. Cambié :nuevo por :old y dejé de usar los alias, y funcionó a la perfección. Gracias!

Comment: Ya lo pongo como respuesta para que los demás lo vean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo extraño es que un trigger se invalida sólo cuando cambia algo en la estructura de los objetos que usa. De hecho, si intentas usar el trigger, oracle va a intentar recompilarlo y es ahí donde sale el error en el título.

¿Por otra parte, estás seguro que debes insertar `:NUEVO` y no `:VIEJO` en la tabla de backup? Estás haciendo un trigger `BEFORE DELETE` (borrando), así que no hay nada en `:NUEVO`, sólo en `:VIEJO`.